# Spivak 24-19 answer

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Question 24-19 from Spivak's calclus:

[image]

I have a small issue with the solution to 24-19 in Spivak's calculus presented below:

[image]

Although the part in highlight makes intuitive sense to me, I can't seem to express the logic rigorously.  In particular I don't see how we can get to an inequality with an infinite number of terms from the inequality with only a finite number of turns.  Can anyone present how the highlight is derived more clearly?

Comment: Fixed a typo. Vigor is important but rigor is more important in math.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Ha did I type vigorously?  Anyway are you able to help with this issue I have?  Should I add the original question for clarification?

Comment: It would be better to have the original question also.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I added the question.

Comment: I checked Abel's Lemma as well and it turns out that the Yellow line is nothing but taking limit as $n\to\infty$ in Abel's Lemma.